# React Context - useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Is it correct that a useEffect is listening to the context?

```
const {
  data,
} = useContext(AuthContext);

async function getProfile() {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      console.info('getProfile called', data.token);
      const response = await getByToken(data.token);
      if (response && response.ok) {
        setFirstName(response.userData.firstName);
        setLastName(response.userData.lastName);
        setEmail(response.userData.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.info('Error', e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.userData) {
      getProfile();
    }
  }, [data.userData]);
```

This is the way I found to make it make calls to getProfile with a userData different from null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is how it works. Although it might be incorrect to say that `useEffect` is listening to changes in the variable. The callback inside `useEffect` runs because of 2 conditions being fulfilled:

1. a render happens.
2. the dependency array has a **changing** dependency

The rerender is because the context value has changed and the inner component is a **Consumer** of the `Context` (cause it calls useContext).
And since the dependency included in the useEffect dependency array also changes, the callback is run.

[A sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-forked-tbufp0) with a simple example